# PRISM / MEF : ModuleExportAttribute vs ExportAttribute?

Tags: dependency-injection, module, export, prism, mef

I don't understand what the difference here is, anyone care to explain how a ModuleExport is different than an Export?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ModuleExport` *is an* `ExportAttribute`, but with some additional module-specific properties.

If you look at the [source code for `ModuleExport`](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/52595#1024668) you find that it has all of the properties of an ExportAttribute, plus:

1. ModuleName
2. ModuleType
3. Module Dependencies
4. Module Initialization

All of these come from the [interface IModuleExport](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/52595#1024402).

If you look at the [`ImportedModules` property of `MefModuleManager`](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/52595#1024939) (the class responsible for finding modules), you see that is imports them all using the `IModuleExport` interface, so this why you are required to use an attribute implementing `IModuleExport`, rather than just straight up `[ExportAttribute(typeof(IModule))]`.

Hope this is what you were looking for.